# Pandas string extract all the matches

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am learning regex operation in pandas series string method. I was able to extract the first number from the string, but my regex is not matching the second number. How to capture both the numbers?

Note that second row, the second element is NAN here.

CODE:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ["number 1.23 has 1.2 ",
                         "number 12.2 has 12 "]})

pat = r""".+\s+
(\d+\.\d+)
.+
((?:\d+\.\d+)?)
.+"""


df['a'].str.extract(pat,flags=re.X,expand=True)
```

Gives:

```
0      1
1.23
12.2
```

Expected:

```
0    1
1.23 1.2
12.2 NaN
```

How to fix the regex?

I am very new to regex, so please be considerate and forgive my ignorance.

Comment: [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for findall

Comment: Use `.str.extractall` with `r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)'` regex

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Gives pattern contains no capture groups.

Comment: Try this `(\d+\.\d+).+(\d+\.\d+)`

Comment: `r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)'` has a capturing group. Please re-try.

Comment: Maybe you want `df['a'].str.extractall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)').unstack().apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x))` or `df['a'].str.extractall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)').unstack().fillna('').apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, that solves the problem.

Comment: @MilkyWay007 Note that `.+` will match *anything* except an empty string. If you want that match to stop before it matches the space, try using  `\w+` instead. (You also could use the [non-greedy](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) qualifier (as in `.+?`), but that adds complication and a performance hit.)

Comment: Also, you could have gotten a wider audience for your question by showing us an example that did not use pandas. There are many folks who can answer your regex questions who don't even know python, let alone pandas. The great thing about learning regexes is, you can take that knowledge with you to a new language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with the `\d+\.\d+` regex:

```
>>> df['a'].str.findall(r"\d+\.\d+").to_frame()
             a
0  [1.23, 1.2]
1       [12.2]
```

Or,

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df['a'].str.findall(r"\d+\.\d+").tolist())
      0     1
0  1.23   1.2
1  12.2  None
```

The  pattern matches

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\.` - dot
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.

Note that `str.findall` does not require the whole pattern to be wrapped with a capturing group, as is the case with `.str.extractall` that could also be used here.

Comment: I want np.nan instead of 12 the last element.

Comment: @MilkyWay007 What do you mean? That you only want to extract float values?

Comment: I got it, `df['a'].str.findall(r"(\d+\.\d+)").to_frame()`. Thanks.

Comment: I mean I only want to capute numbers with decimal, 12 does not have decimal so, it must be np.nan or empty. It was given in question end part.

Comment: @MilkyWay007 Well, that explains all, I adjusted the answer. Note that `findall` does not require the whole pattern to be wrapped with a capturing group.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df['a'].str.findall(r"\d+\.\d+").tolist())`